# For the sake of argument if fadak was to be inherited who are the inheritors other than fatima?

Tags: quran, hadith, shiism, prophets, inheritance

Some people only champion for the cause of Fatima, if fadak was to be inherited who are the beneficiaries? Why people don't stand up for the cause of other beneficiaries?

I feel fatima and prophets widows (mothers of believers) were beneficiaries from my limited knowledge.

Comment: For this a prophet must be allowed to leave a heritage first. Else the beneficiary is the bayt al-Mal. And that's one of the main issues between Sunni's and Shi'a.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I hope my question is pointing to "for sake of argument". I am setting aside prophets leaving inheritance for a moment. My intention is to make people think from other angles

Comment: All eligible people according to Sharia would inherit from the Holy Prophet (as). As for Fadak and some other properties, the Shia believe that they were particularly left for Fatima (as) and Banu Hashim not other people. Some sources suggest that Fadak was actually a gift for Fatima (as).

Comment: Who among banu hashim? Shia also believe Mahdi will be leader of muslims , but their sources say otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Considering that Fadak was obtained without a war, and with the surrender of its inhabitants, it was not considered as spoils and as anfal, it belonged only to the person of the Prophet. When the verse "وَاتِ ذَا الْقُرْبى حَقَّه" was revealed, the Holy Prophet (PBUH) summoned Hazrat Fatima (PBUH) and gave her Fadak as a gift. But after the death of the Prophet (PBUH), the first caliph took Fadak from Fatima and his efforts to reclaim it were unsuccessful. According to the narrations of the Prophet, before his death, Fadak had given and given a gift to Fatima, peace be upon him, so the discussion about the heirs of the Prophet about Fadak is wrong.

In a dispute with the first caliph, Hazrat Zahra (PBUH) expressed her desire to be a gift, and this was her first claim, and she even brought Imam Ali (AS) and Umm Ayman as witnesses, but when she saw that the gift They do not accept being, he was forced to prove his will through inheritance. And that even if this land was not a gift, it will reach the Imam through inheritance. In inheritance, there was a dialogue between the parties and the opponents only referred to a hadith narrated by Abu Bakr himself (we are the companions of the prophets, not North) [6] and Hazrat Zahra (PBUH) also proved by quoting Quranic verses that Prophets, like all people, inherit from themselves.

Ref.: https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa23196